# UICollectionView within UIScrollView: Long Press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to my `UICollectionView` that is within a subclass of `UIScrollView`. (The `UIScrollView` is paged so there are 3 horizontally stacked `UIViewController`s).

My code to add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.delegate = self;
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
longPress.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

And an `NSLog` in my `handleLongPress:` method. Currently I hold down on a `UICollectionViewCell`, it highlights, but the long press is not activated. I believe my `UIScrollView` subclass is consuming the long press and not passing along to the `UICollectionView`. When I lift my finger, the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method is called.

In my `UIScrollView` subclass, the only customization I have is the following:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(nonnull UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
// This line enables the swipe to delete in the Messaging VC.
return ([otherGestureRecognizer.view.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]);
}
```

This was done to enable cell swiping in my `UITableView`, which is one of the pages of my `UIScrollView`. The swiping works no problem, and I have tried a number of similar checks for `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` here but have not gotten the long press to register yet. Any advice appreciated.

Edit: I have added the long press on another `UICollectionView` and it is functional, but the cell never shows highlighted/selected status. I guess that is a clue as to why I can't get this long press gesture to fire.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was adding the gesture recognizer in the `-init` method. That did not work. Simply moving the code to `-viewDidLoad` fixed the problem.